# VirtualBox Debian8 networking issues on Windows host

Tags: networking, virtualbox, debian

I've built a Debian8 guest with 2 network interfaces

- eth0 in dhcp on my desktop network, bind on 192.168.1.x
- eth1 with static ip in an alternative network on 10.90.90.2

Interfaces do show up and seem to be working with outbound traffic:

- ping network1 router from instance does work (ping 192.168.1.254)
- ping windows host from instance does work (ping 192.168.1.103)

While it seems broken with inbound traffic:

- ping instance from windows host doesn't work (ping 10.90.90.2)
- same as above on ping 192.168.1.x

Also, outbound connections to the external world seems broken:

- ping external world doesn't work (ping google.com or ping google ip address - not a dns issue)

Which could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out.

Apparently, VirtualBox 5.x on Windows requires to be ran with admin privileges.

Since i was running as normal user, i found that for some reason VBox had reset the network settings, messing up my local network.

So, solution was running VBox as administrator, then reconfigure the network.